# Why does my quicksort stop working for arrays larger than ~35000? (C++)

Tags: c++, optimization, quicksort, partitioning

Here's my poorly made implementation:

```
void partition(people * arr, int size){
  if(size <= 1)
    return;

  people pivot = arr[rand() % size];
  int low = 0;
  int high = size - 1;

  while(low < high){
    while(  (arr[low].lname < pivot.lname) || (  (arr[low].fname <  pivot.fname) && (arr[low].lname == pivot.lname)  ) ||
    (  (arr[low].fname ==  pivot.fname) && (arr[low].lname == pivot.lname) && (arr[low].dob < pivot.dob)  )   )
        low += 1;

    while(arr[high].lname > pivot.lname  || ((arr[high].fname > pivot.fname)&&(arr[high].lname == pivot.lname)) ||
    ( (arr[high].fname ==  pivot.fname)&& (arr[high].lname == pivot.lname) && (arr[high].dob > pivot.dob) )   )
        high -= 1;

    people temp = arr[low];
    arr[low] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;
   }

   partition(arr, low);
   partition(&(arr[low+1]), size - low - 1);
}



void kwiksort(people * arr, int size)
{  srand((unsigned int)time(0));
   partition(arr,size);
}
```

The program acts as if its in an infinite loop and essentially freezes.
Also, if anyone could point out some methods to optimize quicksort, that would be great.

Comment: Why are you sure it is freezing and not just performing a lot of calculations that increase its runtime ?

Comment: @DWilches I recorded the sorting times for arrays of various sizes, and when I increase the size of the array from something like 35026 to 35027 I went from a time of <1 second to something that won't finish in 10 minutes. The data being sorted also appears to be without any type of corruption as my mergesort can sort it.

Comment: I would think that your "quicksort" also exposes the same behavior of not finishing if you feed it a smaller range of identical values: since your `partition()` doesn't do any progress it will eventually just run out stack space. If you are unlucky and the second branch is used, it may run for ever due to the tail recursive call not causing a recursion.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem but I would like to point out that the highest number rand returns is RAND_MAX which is 32767.  So as your array size grows your pivot value is going to have a decreasing "quality".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems with your version:
1) Neither loop triggers if both values are equal to pivot (one should)
2) You don't move high and low after the swap (you could forgo retesting those)

Your code will work if you fix just one of those

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem lies with your use of an `int` type for the variable `size`.

Normal `int` variables, if i'm not mistaken, can only take values up to 2^15-1, or 32767. If the value is larger, it will loop around to a negative number. This can cause problems when using `if` statements and such.

Instead of declaring `size` with `int size`, try `long size` or `long long size`. Long integers and long long integers can take larger values than regular integers.

Comment: Certainly a suspicious number, but its been a long time since I've seen a computer that didn't have `sizeof(int) == 4`, not `2`.

Comment: C++ is an old language, which might be why the default size of `int` is only 16 bits. At least there are the alternatives `long` and `long long`.

Comment: In C and C++, `sizeof(int)` was historically the natural machine size, so 32 bits for quite some time. With the advent of computers that offer both 32 and 64 bit operational modes, you typically see 32 bit ints and 64 bit longs. At any rate, I suspect the other answer is correct - much more likely that he's running out of stack space.

Comment: That's not the issue; ints are 4 bytes here.

Comment: The standard `sizeof(int)` appears to depend on the compiler. In many places I find it is quoted to be _at least_ 16 bits. For instance, I use the Code::Blocks compiler, which appears to have 16 bit `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't lie in the number of people being used.

See this self-contained modification of your code, where I added only a main function and the declaration of the "people" structure. Even with something as small as 2 people the algorithm never ends.

This may point to that the right answer, as @dietmar-kühl pointed, is that your algorithm is not making any progress, but it is not frozen.

Check the conditions of both your inner `while`, is there any combination of values that will make your data not entering to either? It seems so. And in that case you will be forever swapping the same pair of `high` and `low`.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

struct people
{
    int lname, fname, dob;
};

void partition(people * arr, int size){
  if(size <= 1)
    return;

  people pivot = arr[rand() % size];
  int low = 0;
  int high = size - 1;

  while(low < high){
    while(  (arr[low].lname < pivot.lname) || (  (arr[low].fname <  pivot.fname) && (arr[low].lname == pivot.lname)  ) ||
    (  (arr[low].fname ==  pivot.fname) && (arr[low].lname == pivot.lname) && (arr[low].dob < pivot.dob)  )   )
        low += 1;

    while(arr[high].lname > pivot.lname  || ((arr[high].fname > pivot.fname)&&(arr[high].lname == pivot.lname)) ||
    ( (arr[high].fname ==  pivot.fname)&& (arr[high].lname == pivot.lname) && (arr[high].dob > pivot.dob) )   )
        high -= 1;

    people temp = arr[low];
    arr[low] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;
   }

   partition(arr, low);
   partition(&(arr[low+1]), size - low - 1);
}

void kwiksort(people * arr, int size)
{  srand((unsigned int)time(0));
   partition(arr,size);
}

int main()
{
    int the_size = 2;
    people* pa = new people[the_size]();
    kwiksort(pa, the_size);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right: the problem isn't that the recursive call is problematic. Instead, if there are identical elements in the range, the loop in partition will never make any progress. The primary reason for that is is that the two conditions are not mutually exclusive as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're initializing your array with `rand()`. Probably, your compiler's standard library uses such a random number generation algorithm that you start to get duplicate values after 35026 invocations. Your algorithm seems to stall even if you feed it with only two items if they are equal.